# FSharpx Excel Type-provider hangs

Tags: excel, f#, type-providers

I am trying to program with FSharpx's type provider for excel.

I am using it in this manner -

```
#r @"FSharpx.TypeProviders.Excel.dll"
open FSharpx
type ETP = FSharpx.ExcelFile< @"Book1.xlsx", "Sheet1">
```

However the program just hangs when declaring ETP above.

I installed Fsharpx via nuget.  I am also using Excel 2013 on Windows 8.

Any clues?  How can I debug this?

An additional observation - I noticed that the declaration of the excel file type provider appears to spawn many excel processes as reported on task manager.

Comment: Hi, this type provider is due for a rewrite, but should work despite its limitations. if you want to see what is going on, you'd need to clone fsharpx and compile it, and change your reference in your main project. after which you launch another IDE and attach to the process (devenv.exe, fsi.exe, or xamarin) that uses it

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my latest pull request: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/pull/236 I have refactored the type provider to use the ExcelDataReader library, instead of relying on Office interop. This should prevent the provider from spawning the Excel process.